# How do I read raw input from a USB device's buttons and translate that into keypresses?

Tags: usb, shortcut-keys, configuration, devices, input-devices

I've been trying to figure out the best way to interface the buttons and a touch strip on a Huion Kamvas 12 graphics tablet with my ubuntu installation. Whilst I was able to get the pen to work with the Digimend kernel drivers, the aforementioned buttons and touch strip don't seem to work out of the box or are supported by Digimend, hence why I'm trying to do this myself.

So far, I was able to use Keymapper to interface the shortcut buttons, but cannot seem to use it (Keymapper that is) to properly map the touch strip. I've tried a few other programs, but but with largely the same issue.

According to the evtest tool, the button events are called 'BTN_0', 'BTN_1', 'BTN_2', etc and the touchstrip event is referred to as 'ABS_WHEEL', with various values to denote where the strip is being touched.

Any ideas/recommendations?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to check Wireshark [USB capture](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB).